# Username and password login for App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, openid, authorization

Are there any libraries that provide username and password login for Google AppEngine?

While I could try rolling one from scratch, I'd rather not try to reinvent the wheel if possible.

If not, would it be possible to turn my application into an OpenId provider and then use it to log in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [EngineAuth](http://code.scotchmedia.com/engineauth/docs/index.html). It has many different options for authentication systems, including email+password authentication.

Comment: would you still advise to use EngineAuth at this point? (Just want to check if you've come across other good options in the last 2 years) Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

GAE, via its [Users API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/), supports three types of login (Google accounts, Google Apps accounts and OpenId). For an example of the latter see [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid).

The type of login used is defined when creating the app, see [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview#Authentication_Options) for further details.